# Prepend commands in PHP CLI interactive mode

Tags: php

How can I start the php interactive mode (`php -a`) with pre-executing certain commands?

The option `-B` (`--process-begin`) seems exactly what I want, but it looks like this can not be combined with `-a-:

```
$ php -B '$x = true; echo $x;' -a
Either execute direct code, process stdin or use a file.
```

The php binary should be invoked from within another php console scripted and then handed over to the user.

Is it possible to supply code before handing over?

Or is there another PHP option which could be used?

Comment: did you consider auto_preprend_file option in your php.cli.ini ?

Answer (score 4):

*Based on @Justin T.'s comment.*

The auto_prepend_file option can be used to include some script:

```
# cat foo.php 
$x = true;

# php -d auto_prepend_file=foo.php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo $x;
1
```

Comment: if you're inside your php project managed by `composer` you can use `php -d auto_prepend_file=vendor/autoload.php -a` in order to launch php in interactive mode aware of all your libraries and bundles in `vendor` directory...