# How do I pass commands to php interactive mode on startup?

Tags: php, bash, zend-framework

I want to use php interactive mode as a command-line interface into my Zend application.  I can currently do this by executing `php -a` and **then** executing the following php code once interactive mode has started up:

```
$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]='<some_path>';
require_once('index.php');
```

After executing those two lines, I'm able to make calls to controllers/services/etc in my zend application and see the output.

What I would like is a way to encompass all three commands into a single command/script so that interactive mode would start up, the two php lines of code would be executed, and I would be left with an interactive php prompt with my zend application loaded.  i.e. I could type `./start_my_app` and at the end of it I have the interactive prompt.

I've tried piping in my two php commands as well as redirecting a file into the `php -a` command and neither worked.

Is this possible?

**Edit**

I looked at the solutions given in question that my question is possibly a duplicate of ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659114/prepend-commands-in-php-cli-interactive-mode)).  However, I do not get the same results when doing the example given in that question.  That question shows a simple example where `$x` is set to `TRUE` in a file, that file is prepended to interactive mode, then `$x` is evaluated in the interactive mode to show that is has a value of `TRUE`.

However in my environment I get a different result:

```
# cat foo.php
$x = true;

# php -d auto_prepend_file=foo.php -a
Interactive mode enabled

$x = true;
php >
php > var_dump($x);
NULL
```

I suppose it's possible that this is just an environmental difference, but what would that difference be?

Comment: Here's answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/15659237/1168382 , but in the nutshell you need to use `-d auto_prepend_file` command line option.  For example to make interactive mode aware of your components in vendor directory run this `php -d auto_prepend_file=vendor/autoload.php -a`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prepend commands in PHP CLI interactive mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659114/prepend-commands-in-php-cli-interactive-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My example in the question is slightly off.  The reason (in my environment anyways) was that `foo.php` did not have the `<?php` tag at the beginning of the file.  When I add that on a line above `$x = true;` then it all behaves as expected.

`foo.php` ends up looking like:

```
<?php
$x = true;
```